# Setting LSB using gpiod_set_array_value

Tags: linux-device-driver, gpio

I have GPIO device which I decided to work with GPIOLIB to control it. This GPIO is 8 bit. I am trying to build driver and check functionality using 8 leds connected to this GPIO.

I can use **gpiod_set_array_value** almost successfully except for one issue:

Sending ascii character B (which is: 0100_0010), triggers the right leds(-x--_--x-).

Sending ascii character A (which is: 0100_0001), tirggers the right leds(-x--_---x).

After that LSB keeps high (its led is always on)

So sending again ascii character B, triggers wrong leds(-x--_--xx).

This happens with any odd number (LSB is '1'), I can't set it to 0 again.

When I try to control this LSB pin individually using **gpiod_set_value**. it is working fine (I can switch it on/off), so I don't think there is a problem in the Hardware.

Can anyone please advise, whout could be the problem

-------------EDIT-----------------

I found one workaround for this problem. May be it is useful for someone:

I had to close the created gpiod descriptor then re-assign it again before setting any value to my gpio. Please see below figure to understand my kernel module configuration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjvMZ.png)

I have no clue actually why it is only working like this.

Comment: It shows clearly out-of-boundary access. You rather check the sizes of your descriptor array and other parameters. Your "workaround" (ugliest hack) just +1 to my theory.

Comment: @0andriy, what do you mean by "out of boundary". If you read my question in which I mentioned that I can set the LSB to logic '1' successfully. but Afterwards it never goes to '0'. Ofcourse the size of array is correctly set to (8) as well as other parameters. I really hope If you can try it yourself

Comment: Show the actual code.